# Concatenate non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I need to consolidate a series of 8 repeating columns into one combined set of 8 columns.

The data is set up in a matrix, with a few hundred unique rows and a few hundred columns that are repeating. There is one set of repeating columns for each row. Each row only has data in one iteration of the 8 columns and the rest are blank. I want to combine the multiple hundred repeating series of 8 columns into one set of merged columns, getting rid of all the blanks.

I'm using excel 2016 and I have tried with my limited understanding to use macros I've found on the web to concatenate columns or select every 8th cell, but I cannot physically click each column/cell I want to combine due to the volume of cells. Is there a way to use offset within the concatenate function to select every 8th cell within a range?

My data set looks like this, with the 8 columns repeating once for each row:

[image]

Ultimately I want to combine the repeating columns into one set of 8 columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of some sample data? As well as any code you've already tried? This helps us help you!

Comment: If you have the most current version of Excel, you can use TEXTJOIN to concatenate the columns together.  Use an empty string as the delimiter and ignore blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INDEX() - MATCH() combination as ARRAY Formula to find the first cell that's not empty on the row:

For row starting at A2 the formula for your first result would be:

```
=INDEX(2:2,1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(2:2)-1+COLUMN(A$2),0))
```

Make sure you press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering the formula instead of ENTER (you'll see the formula gets brackets {} at the end):

```
{=INDEX(2:2,1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(2:2)-1+COLUMN(A$2),0))}
```

Then drag the function down and right to fill the 8 result columns.